# Python Chatterbot Library Training Not Efficient

Tags: python, chatbot, chatterbot

```py
chatbot = ChatBot("Chabot",
                  storage_adapter='chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter',
                  database_uri='sqlite:///english.db',
                  logic_adapters=[
                      {
                          "import_path": "chatterbot.logic.BestMatch",
                          "statement_comparison_function": JaccardSimilarity,
                          "response_selection_method": get_first_response,
                          'maximum_similarity_threshold': 0.01,
                          "default_response": "I am sorry, but I do not understand."
                      }
                  ])    

trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(chatbot)
trainer.train("chatterbot.corpus.english.greetings")
```

**RESULTS**

Me: whats up

Bot: I am sorry, but I do not understand.

Me: what's up

Bot: I am sorry, but I do not understand.

Me: What's up

Bot: Not much.

I've tried with `LevenshteinDistance`, `SynsetDistance`, `SentimentComparison` and `JaccardSimilarity` for `statement_comparison_function`. And `get_most_frequent_response`, `get_first_response` and `get_random_response` for `response_selection_method`. Each still gives the same result as the above which is undesirable for me. I'm at least expecting it can understand "whats up". Is there anything I might have done wrongly?

Update #1
So I've tried with other words, such as "what is the first compute?" and yes, it will understand, and most other conversations performed well, but what's the case with "What's up"? Is there any particular reason that the chatterbot have to get precise input for it to generate the correct answer?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.